# GZIPInputStream is prematurely closed when reading from s3

Tags: java, amazon-s3, bufferedreader, gzipinputstream

```
new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
       new GZIPInputStream(s3Service.getObject(bucket, objectKey).getDataInputStream())))
```

creates Reader that returns null from `readLine()` after ~100 lines if file is greater then several MB.
Not reproducible on gzip files less then 1 MB.
Does anybody knows how to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation of `BufferedReader#readLine()`:

> Returns:
>
> A String containing the contents of the line, not including any line-termination characters, **or null if the end of the stream has been reached**

I would say it pretty clear what this means: The end of the file/stream has been encountered - no more data is available.

Notable quirks with the GZIP format: Multiple files can just be appended to one-another to create a larger file with multiple gzipped objects. It seems that the `GZIPInputStream` only reads the first of those.

That also explains why it is working for "small files". Those contain only one zipped object, so the whole file is read.

Note: If the `GZIPInputStream` determines undestructively that one gzip-file is over, you could just open another `GZIPInputStream` on the same `InputStream` and read multiple objects.

Comment: Hi WorldSEnder. It looks to me that issue is not clear for you. Please read carefully "after ~100 lines if file is greater then several MB". It ss not the end of file. There are about 7000 lines. Thanks!

Comment: @Denys, you are reading from `s3Service.getObject(bucket, objectKey)` how do you know it is about 7000 lines? btw lines are unimportant, we talk about binary data. Can you see if you read exactly `s3Service.getObject(bucket, objectKey).getObjectMetadata().getContentLength()` bytes?

Comment: I know this because I extracted that gzip manually. At this moment I am truing the latest version of jets3t.

Comment: I found root case. gzip file was generated in append mode that probably is not well supported by GZIPOutputStream. Thanks everyone who tried to help! Unfortunately for some reason I can't post this as answer to my question.

Comment: @Denys, I added a sentence to the answer. I guess that is what you mean to say?